# No cv.Point in Python OpenCV on latest stable Debian

Tags: python, opencv, debian

When trying to draw a circle on an image using cv.Circle, I realized that there is no cv.Point function to create a cvPoint in Python OpenCV. I'm using the latest stable version of Debian and I installed all the Python OpenCV packages with Synaptic. How do I create a cvPoint to use with the cv.Circle function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use tuples. Here is example of filled green circle:

```
cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```